# How many ways are there to place $l$ balls in $m$ boxes each of which has $n$ compartments (2)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I asked a question, but have not got any answer. So, I decided to break the question down into more simple questions. Here, you may see [the main question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100941/another-counting-problem-on-the-number-of-ways-to-place-l-balls-in-m-boxes), here [the first part of question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101504/how-many-ways-are-there-to-place-l-balls-in-m-boxes-each-of-which-has-n-co).

Assume that there are $m$ boxes each of which contains $n$ compartments. There are also $l$ balls, where  $\ m\ <\ l\ <\ (m−1)n+2$. Moreover, the balls are the same.

$\bullet\ $ I would like to know how many ways there are to place the balls in the boxes such that

**1)**  Each compartment can hold up to one ball.

**2)** Each box must have at least one ball.

**3)** There are exactly $j$ boxes which contain only one ball.

Without the constraint 3, you may see some answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101504/how-many-ways-are-there-to-place-l-balls-in-m-boxes-each-of-which-has-n-co) which I am not sure about the correctness. For sure, there some $j$s for which constraint 3 can be satisfied. I think $2m-l \leq j\leq \lfloor \frac{mn-l}{n-1}\rfloor $.

I highly appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Are those $j$ boxes fixed or we can choose any $j$ boxes?

Comment: @Gyanshu We may choose any $j$ boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given here  is actually to be considered an addendum to
[the answer given to the other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101504/), where it has been considered the number of ways $C(m,n,l)$ to arrange:
 - $l$ *undistinguishable* balls
 - into $m$ *distinguishable* boxes, each provided with $n$ *distinguishable* compartments
 - counting only the arrangements that contain *no empty boxes* = at least $1$ ball per box.

> Let's now call $C_{2}(m,n,l)$ the number of ways to arrange balls in boxes same as above, but
>    - counting only the arrangements that contain  *at least $2$ balls per box*.

It is evident that the approach described in the previous answer and leading to
the involutory recurrence 4) therein, can be applied here as well.
Briefly,
 - imagine to have the sketch of all the configurations pertaining to  $C_{2}(m,n,l)$;
 - add an additional box aside;
 - transfer one ball at time from the original block to the new box;
 - starting from the 2nd ball, you are constructing a partition of the $(m+1, \, n,\, l)$ arrangement,
 that at each step accounts for $C_{2}(m,n,l-k) \cdot C_{2}(1,n,k)$;
 - the process stops when $k=n$ or $k=l$, but we can sum for $0 \leqslant k \leqslant l$
because by definition $C_{2}(m,n,j) = 0$ for $j \leq 2m$ .

Thus we have

> $$
> C_{\,2} (m + 1,n,l)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integer}\;m,n,l} \right.\quad  =
>  \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,l} \right)} 
> {C_{\,2} (m,n,l - k)\;C_{\,2} (1,n,k)}     \tag {4.a} 
> $$

that is the same recurrence as in previous answer.
But now the **initial conditions** will be

> $$
> C_{\,2} (1,n,l)\quad  = \quad \begin{array}{*{20}c}
>    {n\backslash l} &| &  0 & 1 & {2 \leqslant l}  \\
> \hline
>    0 &| &  0 & 0 & 0  \\
>    1 &| &  0 & 0 & 0  \\
>    {2 \leqslant n} &| &  0 & 0 & {\left( \begin{gathered}
>   n \\ 
>   l \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)}  \\
>  \end{array} \quad \quad  = \quad \left( \begin{gathered}
>   n \\ 
>   l \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right) - \left( \begin{gathered}
>   0 \\ 
>   l \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right) - n\left( \begin{gathered}
>   0 \\ 
>   l - 1 \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)
> $$

so, we have
$$
\begin{gathered}
  C_{\,2} (2,n,l) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,l} \right)} {\left( {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  l - k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) - \left( \begin{gathered}
  0 \\ 
  l - k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) - n\left( \begin{gathered}
  0 \\ 
  l - k - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} \right)\;\left( {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) - \left( \begin{gathered}
  0 \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) - n\left( \begin{gathered}
  0 \\ 
  k - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \left( \begin{gathered}
  2n \\ 
  l \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) - \left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  l \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) - \left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  l - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) - \left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  l \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) + \left( \begin{gathered}
  0 \\ 
  l \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) + n\left( \begin{gathered}
  0 \\ 
  l - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) - n\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  l - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) + n\left( \begin{gathered}
  0 \\ 
  l - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) + n^{\,2} \left( \begin{gathered}
  0 \\ 
  l - 2 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \left( {\left( \begin{gathered}
  2n \\ 
  l \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) - 2\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  l \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) + \left( \begin{gathered}
  0 \\ 
  l \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} \right) - 2n\left( {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  l - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) - \left( \begin{gathered}
  0 \\ 
  l - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} \right) + n^{\,2} \left( \begin{gathered}
  0 \\ 
  l - 2 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;j\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,2} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \left( \begin{gathered}
  2 \\ 
  j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,2} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \begin{gathered}
  2 - j \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  \left( {2 - j - k} \right)n \\ 
  l - j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} } \right)n^{\,j} }  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
Bringing the convolution a few  steps forward, we can realize that the pattern
of the upper and lower terms of the binomials follows the same pattern as that of
$$
\text{conv}\left( {\left( \begin{gathered}  n \\ l \\
\end{gathered}  \right) - \left( \begin{gathered}  0 \\ l \\
\end{gathered}  \right) - n\left( \begin{gathered}  0 \\ l-1 \\
\end{gathered}  \right)} \right) = \sum\limits_{k,\;j} {c_{\,k,\;j} \left( \begin{gathered}  k \\ l-j \\
\end{gathered}  \right)} \quad \overset {\text{pattern}} \longleftrightarrow \quad \left[ {x^{\;k} y^{\;j} } \right]\text{mult}\left( {x^{\,n}  - 1 - ny} \right)
$$
so that we arrive to:

> $$
> \begin{gathered}
>   C_{\,2} (m,n,l)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integer}\;m,n,l} \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
>  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;j\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \left( \begin{gathered}
>   m \\   j \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \begin{gathered}
>   m - j \\  k \\
> \end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
>   \left( {m - j - k} \right)n \\ l-j \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)} } \right)n^{\,j} }  =  \hfill \\
>    = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;j\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m - j} \left( \begin{gathered}
>   m \\ j \\
> \end{gathered}  \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \begin{gathered}
>   j \\ k\\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
>   \left( { j - k} \right)n \\  l-m+j \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)} } \right)n^{\,m - j} }  \hfill \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \tag {5} 
> $$

which I could check on computer for a small range of the parameters and looks correct.

This time, for $m=0$, by definition the result should be null, for whichever values of $n$ and $l$.
The formula above instead gives $C_{2}(0,n,0) = 1$, which does not look plausible.
So we shall limit its validity to $1 \leqslant m$, or correct it for $m=l=0$.

For an algebraic verification of 5), let us consider an additional relation.
We can partition the $C(m,n,l)$ arrangements *with no empty box* into those that contain
 - $0$ boxes with exactly 1 ball, ${m \choose 0}$ ways to choose them, and $C_{2}(m,n,l)$ boxes with at least $2$ balls
 - $1$ boxes with exactly 1 ball, ${m \choose 1}$ ways to choose the box and $n$ ways to place the ball in it, and $C_{2}(m-1,n,l-1)$ boxes with at least $2$ balls
  ...
 - $k$ boxes with exactly 1 ball, ${m \choose k}$ ways to choose the box and $n^k$ ways to place the balls , and $C_{2}(m-k,n,l-k)$ boxes with at least $2$ balls
  ...
 - $m$ boxes with exactly 1 ball, ${m \choose m}$ ways to choose the box and $n^m$ ways to place the balls , and $C_{2}(0,n,l-m)$ boxes with at least $2$ balls.

We can see here that , for $l=m$, the $n^m$ arrangements with exactly $1$ ball per box are legitimate and that this **demands that $$C_{2}(0,n,0) = 1$$**

The above translates into:

> $$
> C(m,n,l) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,m} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
>   m \\ 
>   k \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)n^{\,k} \,C_{\,2} (m - k,n,l - k)}   \tag {6}  
> $$

Computing this relation numerically, for $0 \leqslant n,m \leqslant 10$ and $0 \leqslant l \leqslant nm$ returns a full check, and it is also **fully demonstrable algebraically**.

Then each addendum in formula 6) is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @G Cab, this is not only a correct but also a perfect answer! I really appreciate your taking time to do so. Only, you need to add a "$" a line before the Eq. (6). You made my day!

Comment: @Majid: thanks, corrected. I got very interested to your question because [related to this subject](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125) which I was studying for a while. There is much more about to say, but don't know your interest on the topic, and space here is limited.